# delete all datatables using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

so, I am using datatables along with jQuery, and am a bit stumped as to why this is not working. My HTML looks like this:

```
<table id="surnamePrimaryPartitionTable" border=1 class="display partitionDisplay">
  <caption>Partitions</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr style="background-color: #afeeee;">
      <th>Partition</th>
      <th>CPU %</th>
      <th>Search Count</th>
      <th>Person Count</th>
      <th>Disk Space</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I have several tables, each of which follows a similar format, and each of which uses the partitionDisplay class (really just a class that I use so that I can select all the tables later using jQuery).

So, the problem arises when I try to destroy the datatables. Here is what I have:

```
function DeletePartitionInformation(data) {
  jQuery(".partitionDisplay").each(function(){
    jQuery(this).dataTable().fnDestroy();
  });
  jQuery("table tbody").each(function() {
    jQuery(this).html("");
  })
}
```

This code seems to work correctly for the first table, but throws an exception and doesn't work on any subsequent tables. The javascript error message I am getting is the following:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'asSorting' of undefined

A quick Google search on this error says that it generally arises from having  elements nested in a  tag. This does not appear to be the problem, however. I will post the code for the other three tables to demonstrate this:

```
<table id="surnamePrimarySubpartitionTable" border=1 class="display partitionDisplay">
  <caption>SubPartitions</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr style="background-color: #afeeee;">
      <th>Partition</th>
      <th>SubPartition</th>
      <th>CPU %</th>
      <th>Search Count</th>
      <th>Person Count</th>
      <th>Disk Space</th>
      <th>Begin</th>
      <th>End</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table id="givenNullSurnamePartitionTable" border=1 class="display partitionDisplay">
  <caption>Partitions</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr style="background-color: #98fb98;">
      <th>Partition</th>
      <th>CPU %</th>
      <th>Search Count</th>
      <th>Person Count</th>
      <th>Disk Space</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table id="givenNullSurnameSubpartitionTable" border=1 class="display partitionDisplay">
  <caption>SubPartitions</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr style="background-color: #98fb98;">
      <th>Partition</th>
      <th>SubPartition</th>
      <th>CPU %</th>
      <th>Search Count</th>
      <th>Person Count</th>
      <th>Disk Space</th>
      <th>Begin</th>
      <th>End</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

One final note: I am actually able to get the behavior I want if I use the below code. Obviously I would prefer not to, however, since I'd really like to loop over the elements rather than hard-code the element id's in.

```
function DeletePartitionInformation(data) {
  jQuery("#surnamePrimarySubpartitionTable").dataTable().fnDestroy();
  jQuery("#surnamePrimaryPartitionTable").dataTable().fnDestroy();
  jQuery("#givenNullSurnameSubpartitionTable").dataTable().fnDestroy();
  jQuery("#givenNullSurnamePartitionTable").dataTable().fnDestroy();

  jQuery("table tbody").each(function() {
      jQuery(this).html("");
  })
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'asSorting' of undefined

This seems to suggest it may be trying to destroy `dataTable`s that weren't created.

The [static `fnTables`](http://www.datatables.net/api#fnTables) should give you an `Array` of only the `<table>` elements with a `dataTable`:

```
var tables = $.fn.dataTable.fnTables(true);

$(tables).each(function () {
    $(this).dataTable().fnDestroy();
});
```

Comment: With DataTables 1.10, it is replaced with `destroy()`. Also, it takes a boolean parameter and if true, it also removes the `<table>` DOM element too. [DataTables destroy() method](https://datatables.net/reference/api/destroy())