# Un-initialize data-tables (clear from memory)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, memory, datatables

I'm using [data-tables](https://www.datatables.net) (with jQuery). I have a data-tables set that's taking up too much memory in javascript and slowing down other things.

How can I un-initialize a data-tables table and try to clear up some memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `destroy()` method as suggested [here](https://datatables.net/reference/api/destroy())

```
var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();

$('#tableDestroy').on( 'click', function () {
    table.destroy();
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Destroy()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/destroy()) on the datatable.

```
 $('#dataTable').DataTable().destroy();
```

If you wish to remove all datatables from DOM, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14469876/1350913) answer demonstrates how to.

Comment: The method does not have a cap letter